# div float with width of content

Tags: html, css, mpdf

I'm using MPDF to create a PDF from HTML and CSS.

In my HTML I've a div with float:left; and text-align:right and no width specified. When I print the html to my webbrowser it works good but when I print it to a PDF, the width of the div is 100% and te text in the div printed on the right side of the PDF (because of the text-align right). In my browser the width of the div has the width of the content.

So I want to print the div on the left side of the PDF but with text-align right.

I hope someone can help me!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

hey man you want to print html in different style. So, Use this :

just in print.css, add the div property `text-align:left`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="print.css" media="print"> // media=print if present, used when document is printed :)

media="print" have those styles which have to be used while printing a document! I learn that somewhere!
```

works only in MS IE

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I want to use text-align right and using float for the PDF.

Comment: oh yeah man found some tutorial for you : http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200001.html

Comment: Yes I know how to use print.css but it doesnt solve my problem.